# Raised ellipsis

Tags: superscripts, ellipsis

What's next in the following sequence of LaTeX commands: `\ldots`, `\cdots`?

That is, I want an ellipsis at the top instead of in the middle or the bottom.  The specific situation I have is `f^{'''\cdots''}`, which renders the ellipsis too low (and with odd horizontal spacing, which I know how to tweak).

Comment: Did you try `f^{'''\textsuperscript{$\cdots$}''}`?

Comment: @Sigur, I just used your precise code, but this leaves the final '' higher than the initial ones.

Comment: Even outside the superscript?

Comment: I have no explanation, but yes it is so.

Comment: Note that `f^{'}` is already wrong, it should be `f'`; the same for multiple primes: `f''`, `f'''` and so on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you're using the right quote *inside* the superscript.  that will make the primes
too small.  you should use `\prime` instead.

is this more like what you want?

[image: output of example code]

this was produced with

```
$f^{\prime\prime\prime\cdots\prime\prime}$
```

explanation: the right quote is a shorthand for `$^\prime$`, and special
treatment is given to multiple right quotes so that they won't be recognized as multiple
superscripts (which are considered an error).

Comment: Very nice, not only answers the question but has a good lesson.

Answer (score 6):

You could try `f'''^{\cdots}{}''`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$f'''^{\cdots}{}''$
\end{document}
```

Comment: The final primes might end up at a different height than the starting ones.

Comment: @egreg - Under which conditions *might* the final primes be at a different height than the first few ones? FWIW, the five primes in the example are all on the same height.

Comment: It depends on the height of the math atom to which the leading primes are appended to; the trailing ones are appended to an empty atom no matter what the original atom is.

Answer (score 2):

Note the use of `{}` to avoid some strange *bug*.

```
$f^{'''\textsuperscript{$\cdots$}{}''}$
```

[image]

Without the empty braces `{}` we obtain

[image]

As @barbara beeton said you don't need to use powers. But even in this case you have to use an empty pair of braces. Compare

```
$f'''\textsuperscript{$\cdots$}{}''$
$f'''\textsuperscript{$\cdots$}''$
```

[image]

Comment: What a weird hack, but I admit it works.  I will wait to see if there is a more natural solution before accepting.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not really what I'd call a solution.

Comment: @egreg, well it was only using my small knowledge. :) I'm always learning.